# Crystal Reports String Extraction from Access Memo Field

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Memo field which contains the following string "#Gift Card Number", I need to remove all the text in the Memo field up to and including "#Gift Card Number" leaving me with the card number which I can then format as a bar code.

"#Gift Card Number" may or may not occur in the string so I only want to report the field if it does occur.

The Memo field will contain line feeds and "#Gift Card Number" will always be on the last line.

Thank you in advance for any assistance

Comment: Post some code, what have you tried to extract number from GiftCardNumber?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear. I have no experience of Crystal Reports; I am just trying to make life easier by having a bar code to swipe.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

If you are binding datatable as a datasource to a report, then make sure that you extract the number in the c# code itself.

[Use this link to extract number from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187356/regular-expression-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

[Another link to extract](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4fb0c6b7-9c81-4ff9-a5bb-b9926c7a3911/how-can-i-extract-numbers-only-from-a-string?forum=regexp)

To know how to bind crystal report to a datatable, Please go through the

[How to bind crystal report to a datatable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341272/how-to-bind-crystal-report-to-manually-created-dataset)