# How to convert a string into a number in python?

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have a string as follows: "Frequency 0.00Hz". I wish to extract the value 0.00 but I am unsure of how to do this. Usually I use int() but with the Frequency part I can't do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a regular expression to extract the number from the string.

Comment: Please [edit] to show a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research. For example, the `split()` string method and string slicing (`my_string[:-2]`) would likely be helpful here

Comment: use regex `re.findall(r'[0-9.]+', string)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187356/regular-expression-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex :

```
import re
float(re.search('\w (\d+.\d*)\w', "Frequency 0.00Hz").group(1))
```

Comment: This will fall over if digits and a decimal do not exist.

Comment: each time I do this, it returns: Attribute error: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'group'. Additionally, my Frequency 0.00 Hz changes at each iteration so it could be 20.00Hz etc. Sorry, I'm very new to coding!

Comment: it seems op data follow a certain pattern `frequency <number>hz` and the string which op used to get integer data follow same, so you can consider these facts and just get the no only ignoring string