# How do I parse a string with both letters and integers into string and integer variables in VB.net?

Tags: string, vb.net, split

I am reading strings from a file.  Each string will have a string component followed by 2 integer components separated by a hash.

String Examples:
"A1-8"
"AN9-16"
"OUT16-24"
"CARD32-40"

Is there a simple way to parse these into a string variable and 2 integer variables?
for example with "AN9-16" I want to get

```
StrVar = "AN"
IntVar1 = 9
IntVar2 = 16
```

Thanks in advance.

I haven't really tried anything so far.  I considered looking at each char in the string and then splitting it with the first integer and then with the hash, but that seems over complicated.

Comment: You could split on the hyphen and then use regex to pull the numerics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187356/regular-expression-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: this looks promising.  I will dig into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that shows you how you can "walk through" your string one character at a time to find the delimitations.
You can use [IsNumeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isnumeric) to determine where the text part ends. Then with that position, use [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) to separate both parts. Finally, use [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) to separate the numeric part on the "-":

```
Sub ParseString(value As String)
    Dim position As Integer = 0

    ' Find all non-numeric characters
    Do While Not IsNumeric(value.Substring(position, 1))
        position += 1
    Loop

    ' Extract text part 
    Dim textPart As String = value.Substring(0, position)

    ' Extract numeric part
    Dim numericPart As String = value.Substring(position + 1)

    ' Split numeric part on -
    Dim numericValues As String() = Strings.Split(numericPart, "-")

    MsgBox("Text part: " & textPart & vbCrLf & "First numeric value: " & numericValues(0) & vbCrLf & "Second numeric value: " & numericValues(1))

End Sub
```

This is a primitive way to do things and will fail if your string is not in the format you have described. Nonetheless, it demonstrates how you can break a problem down into easier parts to solve.

---

Going further, you can define a class to return the values from your string:

```
Public Class ItemCode

    Public Property StringValue As String
    Public Property IntegerValue1 As Integer
    Public Property IntegerValue2 As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new instance of the <see cref="ItemCode"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new instance of the <see cref="ItemCode"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="stringValue"></param>
    ''' <param name="integerValue1"></param>
    ''' <param name="integerValue2"></param>
    Public Sub New(stringValue As String, integerValue1 As Integer, integerValue2 As Integer)
        Me.StringValue = stringValue
        Me.IntegerValue1 = integerValue1
        Me.IntegerValue2 = integerValue2
    End Sub

End Class
```

You can use this class as the return value for your parsing function. Here's a version that uses Regular Expressions, using a pattern with subexpressions that that collects the matches in 4 Groups (Groups 1, 2 and 3 contain your values, or empty strings where there's no match):

```
Public Function GetItemCodeUsingRegEx(value As String) As ItemCode
    Dim regEx As New Regex("(\D+)(\d*)-(\d+)")
    Dim matchCollection As MatchCollection = regEx.Matches(value)
    Return New ItemCode(matchCollection(0).Groups(1).Value, CInt(matchCollection(0).Groups(2).Value), CInt(matchCollection(0).Groups(3).Value))
End Function
```

Finally, updating my original answer with this new class:

```
Public Function GetItemCode(value As String) As ItemCode
    Dim position As Integer = 0

    ' Find all non-numeric characters
    Do While Not IsNumeric(value.Substring(position, 1))
        position += 1
    Loop

    ' Extract text part 
    Dim textPart As String = value.Substring(0, position)

    ' Extract numeric part
    Dim numericPart As String = value.Substring(position + 1)

    ' Split numeric part on -
    Dim numericValues As String() = Strings.Split(numericPart, "-")

    Return New ItemCode(textPart, CInt(numericValues(0)), CInt(numericValues(1)))

End Function
```

Comment: This is the approach I considered.  It helps to see your example. Thanks. I'm hoping for something simpler.  Regex may work, but I need to figure out the implementation.

Comment: @UnderHillStudio answer updated with Regex-based function.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into regex and found it too complicated for what I'm trying to do.  I code as a hobby and taking the time to learn regex has a low ROI for me.  I'm sure one of you experts could come up with an expression or two that would do what I need, but this is what I did based on the answer from Etienne.

```
Private Sub ParseString(ByVal FromStr As String, ByRef StrVar As String,
                             ByRef IntVar1 As Integer, ByRef IntVar2 As Integer)
    Dim p = 0
    Do While Not IsNumeric(FromStr.Substring(p, 1))
        p += 1
    Loop

    StrVar = FromStr.Substring(0, p)

    Dim IntVar() = Split(FromStr.Substring(p), "-")
    IntVar1 = IntVar(0)
    IntVar2 = IntVar(1)

End Sub
```